# Setting the iis:WebDirProperties of a single file in WiX

Tags: iis, deployment, wix

I am using WiX to deploy a web application under IIS.

I have no problems setting the different properties of my Web Application using the `iis:WebDirProperties` element.

However, I need to set all *.asmx file security attribute to "Integrated Windows Authentication". Does WiX have the ability to set the property of a single file?

*Note: This file is scattered all throughout the different directories. It would have been trivial all the services are in a separate directory.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No. The WiX toolset does not have the ability to set permissions on individual files today. However, you could open a feature request on it... maybe even implement the fix yourself and submit it to the community?